# Showing this function is continuous $ f:(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

I have the following function:

$$f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R,\quad f:(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$$
I want to show that this function is continuous by showing that $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is an open set.

How do I approach this?

I have proved that the function is a metric already. But I can't think of how elements are mapped for some reason - an thus I can't see where a segment $(a,b)\subset \Bbb R$ would go to in the preimage.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $b > a \geq 0$ (otherwise $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is empty, which is okay). We can write
$$f^{-1}((a,b)) = \{ (x,y) : a < x^2+y^2 < b \} = \{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 < b \} \cap \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq a \}^c$$
This is an intersection of an open ball with radius $\sqrt{b}$ and the complement of a closed ball with radius $\sqrt{a}$. The complement of a closed set is open and the intersection of two open sets is open, hence our set is open.

Comment: If I could understand why the preimage of the interval is an annulus, this would be 100% understood. So the reason for that is: my bounded $t$ in $a\lt t \lt b$ is some $t=x_1^2 + y_1^2$, and so all of the elements on the interval are of this form and bounded, that seems fine. What I don't understand is that $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ give $5\in\Bbb R$ and we can't differentiate which one we go back to. Since it isn't injective, I can't see why we get the annulus(I am probably just slow). Thanks

Comment: If $f: X \to Y$ is any function between sets and $B \subseteq Y$, then by definition $f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in B \}$. So if $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $Y = \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is given by $f((x,y)) = x^2+y^2$ and $B = (a,b)$, then $f^{-1}((a,b)) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f((x,y)) \in (a,b) \} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a < x^2+y^2 < b \}$

Comment: It just follows plainly from the definition of inverse images in other words, nothing more subtle is happening.